# Why is my server response time slow even with cloudflare?

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, page-speed, cloudflare

I've had a website for a while and I'm using the free Cloudflare CDN. My host is a fairly cheap shared one.

I noticed that my website feels a bit slow when it is first loaded. I ran a Google Pagespeed Insights test and received a red flag for Server Response Time, which was 1 second. It consistently scores around the second mark, although every now and then it gets <0.3 seconds.

Does Cloudflare even help with this metric? How can I reduce the server response time on the cheap?

Comment: I've not used Cloudflare, but is it caching your HTML pages? (I'm guessing no), this may help you check: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169556-How-can-I-tell-if-CloudFlare-is-caching-my-site-or-a-specific-file-

Answer (score 2):

Some questions to consider:

- How is your caching model set?
- Is priority set for Origin servers, to respect your aging headers, or to Cloudflare?
- When you examine your HTTP request logs do you see items in the logs which should be served by your CDN?
- Do you have cagey developers who are placing all sorts of dynamic parameters on static resources which are keeping them from being cached as static  resources
- Do you have too early allocation of an Origin-bound resource, such as giving out a default shopping cart, which forces a relationship with the longest path servers with the clients?

These are just a few off the top of my head.  I know I was looking at a client's HTTP logs just a couple of days ago and found that their caching model was all messed up.  They also had Cloudflare and couldn't have been getting a very high cache hit ratio from what I observed.